# How to create WCF proxy without svc file which is hosted in windows apps

Tags: c#, wcf, metadata, app-config

i have two apps. one is winform server end where wcf service is hosted and another is winform client app where i have to add service reference.there is no any svc file. so when i am trying to create service proxy at winform wcf client end just entering the url like

**http://localhost:7998/WPFHost/ or
net.tcp://localhost:7997/WPFHost/** for adding service through service reference then getting error.
**Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:7997/WPFHost/'.**

here i am pasting my full app.config file data of wcf server end where wcf has been hosted. please guide me what is wrong in the app.config for which adding ervice reference not being able to add.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WCFService.Service"
                 behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">

            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7997/WPFHost/"/>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7998/WPFHost/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="tcp"
                      binding="netTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                      contract="ServiceAssembly.IChat"/>

            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:7996/WPFHost/mex"
                      binding="mexTcpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="behaviorConfig">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="tcpBinding"
                     maxBufferSize="67108864"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                     transferMode="Buffered"
                     closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                     openTimeout="00:00:10"
                     receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                     sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                     maxConnections="100">
                <security mode="None">
                </security>
                <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"
                              maxBytesPerRead="67108864"
                              maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
                <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"/>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to create the service proxy to **mex** address which is at port 7996:

```
net.tcp://localhost:7996/WPFHost/mex
```

Comment: yes i did but got same error. have found anything wrong in the app.config file.

Comment: The above configuration worked for me - before running it for the first time a windows firewall pop up and I accept it.

Comment: i want to create proxy. where i try to add service ref and put the url net.tcp://localhost:7996/WPFHost/mex then service ref window gives error for not being able to find out service.i just do not understand why it happen....i have no svc file in my service class.please share if u know any trick.thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need the svc file? All you need is a ServiceHost instance created in your application. Starting the application will start the service, and this way wsdl will be available. Maybe you didnt start the application?

Comment: so u mean i have to start the service first and then i could add the service reference where i can give the url of my service like "net.tcp://localhost:7996/WPFHost/mex" ? am i understand correctly. but people generate proxy using svcutil without starting service first. other than svcutil is there any tool exist which can generate proxy of my service and i will just point my service apps. please guide with info.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. First of all - svcutils tool makes use of WSDL, and based on it, it creates the proxy. 1. If you have a svc file, an extra step is made - based on svc file, internally it creates a WSDL. 2. If you directly give the url of your webservice, the mex address will provide the WSDL.